# Using boto3 to upload files to s3 bucket within specific folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have the code below that uploads files to my s3 bucket. However, I want the file to go into a specific folder if it exists. If the folder does not exist, it should make the folder and then add the file.

This is the line I use the add my files.

```
response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
```

My desired folder name is:

```
<Year>/<Month>/<day>/<this is the file>
```

Obviously each day, we would need to make new folders. How can I do this with boto3?

Comment: What is `///`? And what do you want to do?

Comment: if you provide a prefix to a filename and it exists, s3 will write to the prefix. If it doesn't exist, s3 will create it. If you know which prefix you want to use, you don't have to check if it exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no need to create folders**. Simply uploading an object to a particular path will make the folders automatically 'appear'.

Therefore, your code only needs to figure out the correct full path (Key) for where to upload the object. Assuming that you want it to go to a folder with **today's date**, you would need to create the correct path in `object_name`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

target_key = datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/') + object_name

response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, target_key)
```

However, please note that the AWS Lambda function runs in the UTC timezone, so you might need to adjust the time based on your local timezone.